# Do non-pathogenic organism not have PAMPs? Are there any research paper which proves that a certain microbe is non-pathogenic?

Tags: proteins, immunology, bacteriology, pathogenesis, bacterial-toxins

According to [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1931312809002200)

> PAMPs are delivered along with additional information that can be
>   used by the host to distinguish pathogenic from nonpathogenic
>   microbes and thereby guide the ensuing innate immune
>   response.

Does this statement mean that non-pathogenic bacteria do not have PAMPs? If yes, then how would the host body differentiate between a pathogenic and a non-pathogenic microbe? Is there any well-known source containing a list of non-pathogenic microbes? Are there any research paper which proves that a certain microbe is non-pathogenic?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathogen-associated_molecular_pattern#MAMP